# Connect Raspberry PI and Android device through USB connection

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I've an android app and Raspberry Pi Model 3. I just want to transfer data from android app to Raspberry Pi and vice versa through USB Connection.

I've used a standard USB cable connecting USB-A port to Raspberry Pi and USB-C port to Android device.

I've created a broadcast receiver thinking android device will fire `<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>` event.

But it's of no use, since in this case Raspberry Pi is acting as Host and android device as client.

Is there any possibility if i use OTG cable, it will my android device as host and PI as client ?

Or any other solution to transfer data through serial communication ?

Comment: PS: Alternatively, you could switch the RPi into USB device mode.

Comment: No idea, how to do that ?. Any link or some information regarding that would be great.